# Create string from char[] in c returns wrong value

Tags: c, string, strcat

I have the following code, that declares a `char data[]` with simple JSON data. (`{"x":123,"y":137}`) 17 chars long.

On my main function I then try to copy the `char data[]` char by char and concatenate to a new string using `strcat` function.

When I print the char that I want to concatenate it appears to be the valid char, but when I print the final string, it is wrong.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int getDataLength(){
    return 17;
}
static char data[] = {'{','"','x','"',':','1','2','5',',','"','y','"',':','1','3','7','}'};
char getData(int i){
    return data[i];
}

int main() {
    int dataLength = getDataLength();
    char data[dataLength + 1];
    for(int i=0 ; i < dataLength ; i++){
        char chr = getData(i);
        // --- looking good ---
        printf("%c",chr);
        strcat(data,&chr);
    }
    data[dataLength] = '\0';
    // --- broken string ---
    printf("\n%s",data);
}
```

Output:

```
{"x":125,"y":137}
(���{"x":1%
```

What am I missing?

Comment: An easier way of initializing `data[]` would be `static char data[18] = "{\"x\":123,\"y\":137}";`. Note that this array consists of 18 bytes, not 17; you need an extra byte for the null terminator at the end.

Comment: @MFisherKDX thank you for your inputs, I've dealt with the initialization of the data[0]. how can I concatenate char by char?

Comment: Not related: in addition to the first comment: `sizeof(data);` gives ... the size of the `data` array; this is far more elegant than returning the hardcoded `17`. Initialisation could be done with `static char data[] = "{\"x\":123,\"y\":137}"`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should look at your compiler warnings.

```
strcat(data,&chr);
```

`strcat` expects two strings as parameters. Your second parameter is no string but only a single character.
The nul-termination is missing and you copy random garbage data.

Additionally you don't initialize `data` before you start adding to it.

Both errors cause undefined behaviour in your program.

Comment: Got it, but how can I concatenate that char to the data string?

Comment: What about `data[i] = chr;` ?